# How can I make direct phone-to-phone VoIP calls without Internet (on LAN or Wi-Fi)?

Tags: voip

I'm looking for a way to make VoIP calls between two Android devices without having any intermediate server (SIP server) or an Internet connection. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @unforgettableid It would be useful in emergency situations try reading this -> http://www.slideshare.net/altaiar/mobile-crossplatform-peer-to-peer-p2p-data-sync

Comment: @unforgettableid "Because it isn't there".  This feature is potentially so versatile and useful that not wanting it seems inconceivable.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon:  Fair.  It could be useful in remote locations, such as a secluded hiking trail or campground where there's no signal available.

Comment: @unforgettableid I'm hoping to implement this on phones we use so I can eg talk to my wife "around the property" without making a PSTN call. Serval also allows use of poweramps / external modems in some cases to allow substantrial direct range extension. The phone then is more a useful hardware element in a network than a phone per se. And Open WRT and Serval can be integrated in manners which I have not yet my brain properly acquainted with. ....

Comment: @unforgettableid ... I've just got two daisy exchanged TP-LINK 'Range extenders' daisy chained from my  home WiFi router and sometime "soon" I want to try phone access point to range extender chain. This does not quite meet the original request but is a logical superset of it. Two short range linked smartphones with no other hardware could be used as eg door camera to house interior, car backing camera, hiking group or cycling group connection - with voice video and data, maybe car to car intercom, search and rescue snake chain linkup, ... .

Answer (score 6):

While I've not tried to use my phone like this myself, I found the question interesting enough to do a little googling.  The best search term seemed to be `android wifi|bluetooth walkie talkie`.

The most promising free candidate I found looks to be [Android Intercom](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidintercom&hl=en) - direct phone to phone communication over wifi or BT without an intermediary server or telco.  The most promising paid for app seems to be [WiFi Talkie](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.remaller.android.wifitalkie).

Comment: The OP indicated "*without having any intermediate server (SIP server) or an Internet connection*" which is going against the OP's requirement and question :)

Comment: How is "direct phone to phone communication over wifi or BT without an intermediary server or telco" going against the OP's req of "without having any intermediate server (SIP server) or an Internet connection", exactly?

Comment: The linkys to your answer referred to using a Wifi mechanism, the OP did not give any indication of using *intermediate server* which includes *SIP* and presumably the OP wanted zero third party support, i.e. no wifi, no internet, no connectivity, no SIP.

Comment: *BOTH* links are peer to peer solutions, though the second one does make use of any local wireless LAN (which doesn't require an internet connection.  And you can use SIP without a third party - it's just a protocol, like TCP/IP.

Comment: Logos> How do u use sip without a third-party (like a sip server) - any example code?

Comment: @jasper: this isn't a programming forum - coding isn't the point of the Q/A here.

Answer (score 3):

[Meshenger](https://github.com/dakhnod/Meshenger) seems to be doing what you ask for. It is also available via [f-droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/d.d.meshenger/).

It works on LAN and needs no Internet or intermediate server. No DHCP server is needed, because it can work with IPv6 link local addresses.
WebRTC is used as a transmission protocol for audio and video.